# Why does my application return 'Assertion Failed!' error on some systems?

Tags: c#, c++, assert, assertions, assertion

Hi I have a C# web application

with a C# ActiveX tool that connects to the user's hardware to collect information.

anyways all works fine on most computer

except on some it shows me a (sometime on resetting of CAS permissions it works but soon starts throwing a fit)

"Assertion failed!" error
(See screenshot)

new SecurityPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted).Assert();

but the Error says it is "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library" exception and from a completely different program NCS2Prov.exe which a bit of googling tells me is due to the network adapter.

My applications runs on the internet and has the right CAS permissions - is there any reason that the CAS permission might have been revoked?

Some clues on the internet tell me to reinstall the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime library -- will reinstalling .net Framework 2.0 do the same thing?

[image]

Comment: Show us the source for NCSRuleReader.cpp

Comment: "My applications runs the internet"! LOL.  Possibly better than "All your base..."

Comment: @Shiftbit -- umm it's not even my code

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing the [Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)
which I believe can resolve your issue.